# Accessing a readonly property

Tags: objective-c, theos

I have found this property in an header file:

```
@property(readonly) UIImage *wallpaperImage;
```

but, as you can see it is `readonly`. I have read about class extensions, so in my main tweak file I have written this:

```
@interface SBFWallpaperView ()

@property(readwrite) UIImage *wallpaperImage;

@end
```

But it doesn't work. As I try to use `[obj setWallpaperImage:image];` SpringBoard dies. What should I do? I also cannot find a valid instance variable to hook with MSHookIvar, so I'm really clueless of what to do. Thanks in advance if you can help me!

Also, I should specify: `obj` is an object of type `SBFWallpaperView`, which I got by MSHooking a `SBFWallpaperView` ivar.

Answer (score 0):

If the property is marked `readonly` in a header, you should change it to not be `readonly` in the header.  If you don't own the header, there isn't much you can do.  Without more context, it's hard to advise you on a work-around, but consider something like creating a new instance of `SBFWallpaperView`?  Perhaps it has an `initWithImage:` method?

Comment: The class has a `initWithFrame:(CGRect)arg1`, but I really don't think it has anything to do with the wallpaper image I am trying to change.